# Neo4j 5.10 is not working with the latest gds

Tags: plugins, neo4j

I had to uninstall my neo4j on the server, and installed the latest version (5.10).
added apoc, worked fine and after that added gds2.4.1.
Then edited the config file and restarted neo4j. It said it start and running on pidxx, but nothing loads.
I checked again and neo4j was not running.
I deleted the gds.jar file from plugin directory and it worked again. Is it a version mismatch or some thing else?

Thanks in advance!

````
    at org.neo4j.server.startup.Bootloader$Dbms.status(Bootloader.java:543)
    at org.neo4j.server.startup.StatusCommand.execute(StatusCommand.java:37)
    at org.neo4j.cli.AbstractCommand.call(AbstractCommand.java:92)
    at org.neo4j.cli.AbstractCommand.call(AbstractCommand.java:37)
    at picocli.CommandLine.executeUserObject(CommandLine.java:2041)
    at picocli.CommandLine.access$1500(CommandLine.java:148)
    at picocli.CommandLine$RunLast.executeUserObjectOfLastSubcommandWithSameParent(CommandLine.java:2461)
    at picocli.CommandLine$RunLast.handle(CommandLine.java:2453)
    at picocli.CommandLine$RunLast.handle(CommandLine.java:2415)
    at picocli.CommandLine$AbstractParseResultHandler.execute(CommandLine.java:2273)
    at picocli.CommandLine$RunLast.execute(CommandLine.java:2417)
    at picocli.CommandLine.execute(CommandLine.java:2170)
    at org.neo4j.server.startup.Neo4jAdminCommand.call(Neo4jAdminCommand.java:123)
    at org.neo4j.server.startup.Neo4jAdminCommand.call(Neo4jAdminCommand.java:42)
    at picocli.CommandLine.executeUserObject(CommandLine.java:2041)
    at picocli.CommandLine.access$1500(CommandLine.java:148)
    at picocli.CommandLine$RunLast.executeUserObjectOfLastSubcommandWithSameParent(CommandLine.java:2461)
    at picocli.CommandLine$RunLast.handle(CommandLine.java:2453)
    at picocli.CommandLine$RunLast.handle(CommandLine.java:2415)
    at picocli.CommandLine$AbstractParseResultHandler.execute(CommandLine.java:2273)
    at picocli.CommandLine$RunLast.execute(CommandLine.java:2417)
    at picocli.CommandLine.execute(CommandLine.java:2170)
    at org.neo4j.server.startup.Neo4jCommand.main(Neo4jCommand.java:41)
    at org.neo4j.server.startup.Neo4jBoot.main(Neo4jBoot.java:30) ```
````

Answer (score 0):

They updated the version control and it is a version mismatch.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).